# Redirect::intended laravel doesnt work when accessing link from email

Tags: php, laravel

so I use redirect::intended to redirect the page to intended URL after successful login. if i type the URL directly from browser its working, but it doesn't work when I access the link from email or any other sites. can anyone tell me why and what is the solution? thanks in advance.

the code is:

```
Return Redirect::intended('/');
```

Comment: if you type what URL directly into the browser?

Answer (score 0):

`intended()` checks if the session index `url.intended` exists and redirects to it by default or else redirect to `$default='/'` which can be overwritten.
check session index

Comment: i dont get what you saying. it doesnt work when i access the link from external sites e.g whatsapp, gmail, etc. i check the url intended session and it always null if i access the link from external sites.